# Android table with locked headers

Tags: android

I need a table like widget, in which I can lock the 1st row and column.

The end result needs to be something like the screenshots below.
Currently I am using https://github.com/InQBarna/TableFixHeaders for this. But this is giving to much NullPointerException crashes caused by the OS cleaning up variables and stuff.

Is there some other library or something build in into Android to create a View like this ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found this library which is very powerfull : [GitHub](https://github.com/evrencoskun/TableView)

Tell me if it's ok for your needs